# Run Grails 3 standalone jar/war with HTTPS

Tags: java, gradle, grails, https

I can run my Grails 3.3.8 application with HTTPS by using `-https` argument (https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/run-app.html).

`grails run-app -https`

Application is accessible on https://localhost:8444 (I use custom port, 8443 is default).

I have created a runnable `war` file using a `grails package` command, as mentioned in https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/deployment.html. After executing

`java -jar PATH_TO_APP\myapp-0.1.war`

application runs correctly on http://localhost:8080.

#### Problem

I can't figure out though how to run this `jar` with `-https` argument, so it's accessible on https://localhost:8444 - as with `grails run-app -https`. Can I make runnable `jar/war` run in HTTPS mode? Or maybe I can default my application to run with `-https`?

#### What I have tried:

- Executing `jar` with `--Dserver.port.https=8444` parameter - to no effect.
- Executing `grails package -https` - I don't know what I expected.
- The plugin https://grails.org/plugin/standalone, which looks like it could help - unfortunately unavailable for Grails 3.

#### Additional info

I have configured this application to use a certificate and custom port, but I don't think it matters an this point:

-> `build.gradle`.

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs("-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always")
    addResources = true
    String springProfilesActive = "spring.profiles.active"
    systemProperty springProfilesActive,     System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
    systemProperty "server.port", "8444"
    systemProperty "server.ssl.enabled", "true"
    systemProperty "server.ssl.key-store", System.getProperty("user.home") + "/certificates/cert.p12"
    systemProperty "server.ssl.key-store-password", "secret"
    systemProperty "server.ssl.key-password", "secret"
}
```

#### Specification:

- System: Windows 10
- JDK: 1.8.0_191-b12
- Grails: 3.3.8

---

#### Edit: I tried using @erichelgeson answer.

I re-exported my certificate with an alias `tomcat`:

`openssl pkcs12 -export -out ia.p12 -inkey ia.key -in ia.crt -chain -CAfile ca.crt -name tomcat`,

and imported it with `keystore` command (I'm on Windows using Windows Subsystem for Linux)

`/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_191/bin/keytool.exe -importkeystore -srckeystore cert.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcalias tomcat -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass secret -destalias tomcat`,

and then migrated it to PKCS12 after keystore warning

`/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_191/bin/keytool.exe -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12`.

I placed `keystore.jks` in root of application folder (I also tried `/src/main/resources`) and modified my `application.yml` file by adding

```
server:
  port: 8444
  ssl:
    key-password: secret
    key-store-password: secret
    key-store: keystore.jks
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: tomcat
```

Application won't start throwing error `DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big` or - after commenting out `key-store-type: PKCS12`: `Alias name [tomcat] does not identify a key entry`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to generate the key with these options:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 365
```

application.yml/groovy:

```
server:
   port: 8444
   ssl:
      key-store: keystore.p12
      key-store-password: whatYouSetWhenGeneratingKeytool
      keyStoreType: PKCS12
      keyAlias: tomcat
```

Your app will start with ssl - though the output will say http, it's actually https:

```
$ ./gradlew assemble
$ java -jar build/libs/ssltest-0.1.jar
Grails application running at http://localhost:8444 in environment: production
```

Tested with Grails 3.3.8.

The embedded tomcat/container is provided by spring-boot so take a look at their docs for a lot more info/options.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.17.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer. Unfortunetely I still can't get it to work - I surely do something wrong, or it's some weird Windows issue. I'll edit my question to explain my new problems, but could you tell me where do you put the `keystore.p12` file? I tried placing it in root folder of my app and in `/src/main/resources`, and using absolute path like `C://Users/..`, and I think it may not be picked up by an app.

Comment: Please read the docs carefully - if you'd like to read the key-store off the classpath use the syntax `key-store: classpath:keystore.jks`. Your update question seems more to do with the process of export/import. Try a new generated key with keytool first to verify it works first.

Comment: I feel like a moron, but the problem was that I was still trying to launch the application using `run-app -https` (for testing). Without `-https`, the app runs both with yours and mine certificates. Thank you for your help and patience.

For completeness: I've put the `keystore.jks` into `/src/main/resources/certificates` and added `key-store: classpath:certificates/keystore.jks` into `application.yml`. I'm preparing the executable `jar` with the command `grails package` (which is practically the same as `assemble`).

Comment: Great! Glad you got it sorted out.